# How to change the color background dynamically with tailwindcss-themer plugin in next js with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

i wanted to chnage the background color when i click on button . with the help of tailwindcss-themer plugin
i aslo changing the color with the help of redux toolkit.kindly help me i don't know where i could a

mistake here is my code this is my theme where update the ui

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function ThemeSwitcher() {
  const itemColor = [
    { name: 'Light', value: 'light' },
    { name: 'Dark', value: 'dark' }
  ]
  const themeColor = useSelector((state: any) => state.themes.theme)
  const selectedObj =
    itemColor && itemColor.find((v: any) => v.value == themeColor)
  console.log(selectedObj)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const handleSetTheme = (newTheme: any) => {
    console.log('newTheme', newTheme)
    dispatch(setTheme({ theme: newTheme }))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Theme: {themeColor}</p>
      {itemColor?.map((i, index) => {
        return (
          <span key={`item-${index}`} className="mr10">
            <p>{i?.name} </p>
            <button onClick={() => handleSetTheme(i.value)}> theme</button>
          </span>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThemeSwitcher
```

here is my redux toolkit code

```
const initialState = {
  theme: ['light', 'dark']
}

export const ThemeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'themes',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTheme: (state, action) => {
      // Set the theme to a specific value from the action payload
      console.log('theme', action.payload)
      state.theme = action.payload.theme
    }
  }
})
export const {setTheme } = ThemeSlice.actions
export default ThemeSlice.reducer
```

here is my configuration file

```
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('tailwindcss-themer')({
      defaultTheme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            primary: '#344767',
            'primary-light': '#e5f3fe',
            secondary: '#98a2b2',
            dark: '#344767',
            grey: '#848484',
            'secondary-dark': '#aeaeb280',
            'secondary-light': '#fcfcfc',
            'secondary-black': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)',
            'secondary-gray': '#67748e',
            main: '#26292D',
            inner: '#282B2F',
            setting: '#469E9B',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08)',
            transparentBg: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03)',
            'light-black': '#969696',
            skeletonClr: '#a2a2a259',
            btn: '#cb0c9f',
            footer: '#8392AB',
            background: '#f8f9fa',
            sidebar: '#67748e',
            darktheme: '#111322',
            darksidetheme: '#cfd0d3'
          }
        }
      },
      themes: [
        {
          name: 'light',

          extend: {
            colors: {
              primary: '#344767',
              'primary-light': '#e5f3fe',
              secondary: '#98a2b2',
              dark: '#344767',
              grey: '#848484',
              'secondary-dark': '#aeaeb280',
              'secondary-light': '#fcfcfc',
              'secondary-black': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)',
              'secondary-gray': '#67748e',
              main: '#26292D',
              inner: '#282B2F',
              setting: '#469E9B',
              borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08)',
              transparentBg: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03)',
              'light-black': '#969696',
              skeletonClr: '#a2a2a259',
              btn: '#cb0c9f',
              footer: '#8392AB',
              backgound: '#f8f9fa',
              sidebar: '#67748e',
              darktheme: '#111322',
              darksidetheme: '#cfd0d3'
            }
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'dark',
          extend: {
            colors: {
              background: '#141728',
              primary: '#67748e',
              secondary: '#111322',
              dark: '#cfd0d3'
              // sidebar: '#67748e',
              // darktheme: '#111322',
              // darksidetheme: '#cfd0d3'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
```

i wanted to change the color which i given in the plugin .. here is my code . given the optimize solution